# how to encrypt the information in iPhone using a 1024-bit asymmetric public/private key scheme?

Tags: iphone, encryption-asymmetric

I want to encrypt some data like  image,sound file or text .is there any tutorial/example available for encryption using a 1024-bit asymmetric public/private key.

please provide any link available for the encryption in iphone..

Answer (score 1):

Greg Haygood seems to have the only post on the internet that deals with asymmetric encryption on the iPhone. Here's a link to his post which includes most of the code you'd need. http://greghaygood.com/2009/01/17/asymmetric-encryption-with-the-iphone-sdk-and-securityframework

If anyone has found other solutions or documentation please share.

Comment: Thanks cesarislaw  for your help